Does the nvim-jdtls support method or field in addition to class for lsp_workspace_symbol?
I noticed that when I use :Telescope lsp_workspace_symbol query=xxx I only get results of type class, in other words it only find classes with that xxx in the name, but not methods, fields, constructors, packages, etc.
When I use :Telescope lsp_document_symbol it will find classes, methods, fields, etc. but not when using :Telescope lsp_workspace_symbol or :Telescope lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbol.
Why is that? Is it a limitation of the language server  eclipse.jdt.ls/jdtls or it's a limitation of the lsp client nvim-jdtls?  Or did I misconfigure something?

From this answer
jdtls does support method in the workspace via the includeSourceMethodsDeclarations configuration settings that is false by default. So the workspace search for symbols will be limited to types (class) and method.
To enable the method search you need to configure nvim-jdtls like this:
local config = {
...
settings = {
  java = {
    symbols = {
      includeSourceMethodDeclarations = true,
    }
  },
}
...
}
require("jdtls").start_or_attach(config)

The other configuration settings for jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls can be inferred from https://github.com/eclipse-jdtls/eclipse.jdt.ls/wiki/Running-the-JAVA-LS-server-from-the-command-line#initialize-request (currently the only "symbol" options is includeSourceMethodDeclarations).
